# react parent component re-rendering again after all components have been rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, render

## Here's my code

```js
// App.js
import { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [isInvalid, setIsInvalid] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value);
  const handleInvalid = (isValue) => setIsInvalid(isValue);

  console.log("parent", isInvalid);

  return (
    <Child
      value={value}
      handleInvalid={handleInvalid}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```

```js
//Child.js
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Child({ value, handleInvalid, handleChange }) {
  console.log("child");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("child effect");
    handleInvalid(!(Number(value) >= Number(0) && Number(value) <= Number(24)));
  }, [value, handleInvalid]);

  return (
    <input
      type="number"
      min={0}
      max={24}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```

run => https://codesandbox.io/s/bumo-jasig-rendeoring-sunseo-isyu-forked-08gszy?from-embed

## Problem

When the components are first rendered, they work as expected.
like this:

```bash
parent false
child
child effect
```

However, if I change the input value, the result is like this:

```bash
parent false
child 
child effect 
parent false
```

As you can see, the parent component is rendered once more at the end.
What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `handleInvalid` function to call the setter function only if value actually changed:

```
const handleInvalid = (isValue) => isValue !== isInvalid && setIsInvalid(isValue);

// or, lengthier
// const handleInvalid = (isValue) => { if (isValue !== isInvalid) setIsInvalid(isValue) };
```

Currently, each change of input in Child component fires two setters on Parent:

- `handleChange`, which calls `setValue(...)`, triggering the first Parent rerender
- `handleInvalid` (as part of Child `useEffect`), which **always** calls `setIsInvalid(...)`. It happens while Parent component is still not 'finalized' (that's the difference with initial render, when `handleInvalid` is called as well as part of Child "mounting"), hence render function for Parent is called twice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Because the setter is called once more while the parent component is not yet 'finalized', so the parent component is rendered once more and the child component is not re-rendered?

Comment: Yes, as there's no actual need to rerender child component in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You declare states at `Parent` and pass them to `Child` via props.

so `Parent` will re-render whenever its states change

have no problem here